# What's the DB independent (works for both mysql and sqlite3) solution to calculate days between two dates in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, date

Datediff is the function used in mysql and sql server to calculate the days between two dates. However Datediff does not work in sqlite3. What's the DB independent (works for both mysql and sqlite3) way to calculate days between two dates? Thanks so much.

Comment: The ANSI SQL (i.e. DB independent) solution would be `date1 - date2` but none of the DBMS you mentioned is compliant with the standard when it comes to date handling, so you will have to maintain different SQL for different DBMS.

Comment: sqlite stores date as a string or int or real [datatype3](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime). you can use unixtimestamp in both.

Answer (score 0):

If you manage your data types in the correct fashion, it is possible to make the subtraction work properly, and in the same way, in all 3 systems.

Because SQLite does not have a datetime data type, you can store the date values as integers, and subtract dates normally.

MSSQL allows subtraction of datetime, and when cast as an int, will give you the number of days between them.

MySQL should allow subtraction of DATE data types. (You can check this.)